# Facebook if($user) command isnt understanding the state of user

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress

Im trying to check if user accepted my app on wordpress, and is working in default wordpress links like: 
example.com/?p=15
but not in seo urls like:
example.com/postname

Im using:

```
$user = $facebook->getUser(); 
if ($user) {........
```

but seems with wordpress permalinks it cant check the state of user, any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Usually "not working" is considered a *bad* explanation of the problem.

Comment: Sorry for explanation, im not that good in english
since in wordpress without seo urls is working, seems with permalinks isnt, the links is looking something like
example.com/post?state=xxxxxxxxxx
and if $user is not understanding the state value
but in example.com/?p=15?state=xxxxxxxx
is just working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check if all urls generated by your wordpress is under app canvas url.
Then check if you're initiating $facebook variable as an instance of facebook library, like following:

```
  require_once("facebook.php");

  $config = array();
  $config[‘appId’] = 'YOUR_APP_ID';
  $config[‘secret’] = 'YOUR_APP_SECRET';
  $config[‘fileUpload’] = false; // optional

  $facebook = new Facebook($config);
```

Comment: Yes im using this way, but since is working without permalinks (without .htaccess) i think problem is to links something, or maybe to see anyway to exclude this file from htaccess